# Generating encoded URL's for file sharing stored on amazon S3

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, amazon-s3

I am working on file sharing for objects stored on amazon S3.Now the path for the object stored on S3 is default like this `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/path_to_file/file_name.jpg/docx` etc.Now I want to share these file URLs via email through my app.
Currently when I share I see the entire URL as is in the email.I want it to be sent in an encoded form so that its hard to guess the exact location of the file.

I am using PHP and I was planning to use `base_64_encode/decode` functions or `md5` the URLs but not sure if thats the right way to go.

So,I am looking for some tool or API (by amazon ot 3rd party) that can do it for me.
I would also like to shorten the URLs while sharing.

Would like to seek advice and guidance from someone implemented something similar.
Not sure if it comes under **URL-REWRITING** but tagging it under it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this:

1. You can map your url and s3's url in your server, and give your url to user. When user make request to your url, redirect it to s3's. You can ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection
2. You can call API provided by url redirect service provider, e.g. tiny.cc/api-docs